# In Fortran90, use variable string as file name when opening files for read/write

Tags: file-io, fortran, access-violation

I am writing code in Fortan90 (Intel fortran in MS Visual Studio 17), where I am trying to use a variable string to open files for read/write.  I read a variable length [base name] from an input file, append either prefixes or suffixes, depending on whether the file is an input or output file and the type of data in the file.  I have been able to successfully read [base name] and append the prefix/suffix (use a sample code to print out the results, as far as I can tell, all file names are correct)

However, when I try to use FILE=[character-string], I get an access violation on the read line.

code:

```
Character (40) :: bname
Character (50) :: inname1, inname2, ....
Character (50) :: outname1, outname2, ....

inname1 = 'LON_'//TRIM(bname)//'.txt'

outname1 = TRIM(bname)//'_DATA.csv'

OPEN(30, FILE=inname1, STATUS='OLD')
OPEN (40, FILE=outname1, STATUS='NEW')
```

I have used STATUS='UNKNOWN' with no effect.  Tried to use an allocatable length for the file names (CHARACTER (LEN:=), ALLOCATABLE ::), but this resulted in the names being truncated to only the first part for those with a leading string and an error for those with the base name leading.

Please note, I am very inexperienced.  I can access this website on one computer, in a different building than the one where I am writing the code, so can't copy code directly.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please also use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Be aware that Fortran 90 is just one very old revision of the Fortran standard. Compilers usually care about Fortran 95 as the oldest reasonable base. The current revision is Fortran 2018.

Comment: You have to show your complete code. Please see also [mcve]. If you cannot copy the actual production code, create a different minimal reproducible example. Please note especially the *reproducible*. We should be able to reproduce the error from the code you would show.

Comment: Thank you.  I can not copy the code that was giving the error.  I tried to reproduce it on another computer, with a newer version of Visual Studio (code is on VS 2017, repeated with VS 2022).  I could not reproduce the error on the other computer and got output that is correct for the values entered.  I will take a printout of the code back to the original system and see if I can figure out if the difference is in something I did different or possibly VS version.